# Apache camel write to rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am trying to read data from a file and write to a rabbitmq queue using apache camel but ending up with the error

```java
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[rabbitmq://localhost:15672?queue=hello] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file://target/?fileName=doctor.txt&chars... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: rabbitmq://localhost:15672?queue=hello due to: No URI path as the exchangeName for the RabbitMQEndpoint, the URI is rabbitmq://localhost:15672?queue=hello
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:945)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:794)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2184)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1916)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1777)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1745)
    at test.RMQCamelSender.main(RMQCamelSender.java:38)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: rabbitmq://localhost:15672?queue=hello due to: No URI path as the exchangeName for the RabbitMQEndpoint, the URI is rabbitmq://localhost:15672?queue=hello
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:202)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:106)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:112)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:55)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:500)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:213)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:942)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URI path as the exchangeName for the RabbitMQEndpoint, the URI is rabbitmq://localhost:15672?queue=hello
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQComponent.createEndpoint(RabbitMQComponent.java:50)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQComponent.createEndpoint(RabbitMQComponent.java:31)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:122)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:525)
    ... 17 more
```

Following are my implementations of the classes which are creating camel context and rabbitmq queue.

### RMQCamleSender.java

```java
package test;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import test.Producer;

public class RMQCamelSender {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        Producer queueProd = new Producer();
        queueProd.setupConnection();
        System.out.println(queueProd.toString());

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("hello world");
                from("file://target/?fileName=doctor.txt&charset=utf-8")
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                                System.out.println(msg.getIn().getBody(
                                        String.class));

                            }

                        }).to("rabbitmq://localhost:15672?queue=hello");

            }
        });

        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

### Producer.java

```java
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Producer {
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";
    public static Connection connection;

    public void setupConnection() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");

        connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    }

}
```

The program is working fine if I am not using Camel and trying to contact the queue using standard rabbitmq library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty indicative: you are missing the exchange name in your endpoint URI, it cannot be blank, as [the official Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html) says it has to follow the given format:

> rabbitmq://hostname[:port]/exchangeName?[options]

I suggest you try using the `amq.direct` exchange (for more details, refer to the [official RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchanges)), like so:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("hello world");
    from("file://target/?fileName=doctor.txt&charset=utf-8")
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(msg.getIn().getBody(String.class));
            }

        }).to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/amq.direct?routingKey=hello");
}
```

Additionally, you are using `15672` port, which is by default the port for RabbitMQ's web management console, I guess you haven't changed the default settings so the port needs to be `5672`. You also have to use the `routingKey` parameter instead of the `queue` one since in RabbitMQ semantics you publish to `exchange:routingKey` and only consume from queues.

Comment: how to define rabbit configuration through the bean definition.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the rabbitmq exchange name. It is missing from here;

```
.to("rabbitmq://localhost:15672?queue=hello");
```

It should be something like this:

```
.to("rabbitmq://localhost:15672/exchangeName?routingKey=hello");
```

Also, if you are sending to exchange, why do you want to specify a queue? You need only to specify the routing key and the exchange will send to that queue if there is a binding for that routing key.